# Multiple nibs, multiple IBOutlets, one controller. Getting unrecognized selector?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have three nibs, and a SetupController class. In interface builder all nibs have the File's Owner set to "SetupController".

In SetupController header file I have

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *label;     //Nib one (Created with SetupController)
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *label2;    //Nib three
```

In the m file I have:

```
@implementation SetupController

@synthesize label = _label;
@synthesize label2 = _label2;
```

Now, when I attempt to update the NSTextField of label2 using [_label2 setStringValue:@"String"], nothing happens. Opening debug I see _label2 is null, but _label is not.

The second and third nibs (that I can't update) are being loaded in a ViewController with initWithNibName:@"NIB" bundle: nil;

Does loading nibs in this way not properly load outlets ? Since the outlets are instantiated in SetupController, and I load the new view as a new ViewController, are they not loading properly?

Thanks all!

Comment: A few notes. First, you don't need the `@synthesize` directives anymore. They are (almost) never needed. Second, you generally want to declare `IBOutlet` properties as `(weak, nonatomic)`. Third, check to be sure that `label2` is hooked up to a valid text field in your interface builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those @property declarations are in the file's owner class for both Nib one and three, and the same instance of that class loaded both nibs, then perhaps they could both be non-nil.  That is, however a catch-22 since you say you're using an init function in a NSViewController subclass to load the nib. And each VC can only be init'ed once and manage only one view, not two.

So the VC instance where the label property is non-nil must have been init-ed with "Nib one."   label2 is nil because the NSTextField you think it's an outlet to isn't in "Nib one." The IBoutlets get pointed to the view objects when the Nib is loaded, and there's nothing in the Nib being loaded for label2 to point to.

You have to have the outlet to label2 in a VC instance that loads "Nib three."  This would usually be a different class than the VC that loads "Nib one" though I don't know that you can't have two nibs with the same file's owner class, with outlets that are nil depending on what nib each instance of that VC class loads.

Comment: What I'm building is essentially a setup wizard .. so as each view passes I am gaining more and more data from the user, and housing it all in one controller to be neat and make it easier for me. (and I don't know how to properly communicate between views..). So, if I understand correctly what I'm trying to do isn't possible/proper? I am unable to have a IBOutlet load from a nib and attach itself to an Outlet in another class?

Comment: If you have an outlet in a VC that you want to access from another VC, you can do it with a keyPath pretty trivially.  It is significant that your code snippets are somewhat archaic Objective-C syntax.   If you have an instance oneViewController, and it has a property threeViewcontroller that you point to the file's owner instance of nib three after it is loaded, you can just get to three's outlets from one with a keypath of `self.threeViewController.label2` which would be `[[self threeViewController] label2]` in older syntax.  The new dot syntax makes the keypath more clear.

Comment: OK. Got it. I have it working now by holding a reference to the VC after it's loaded and using [[_myVC myLabel] setStringvalue@"Blah"]; I'm curious now as you used the word archaic syntax.. did you mean this method (that I'm not using) is archaic? What is the best way to handle the collection of data throughout multiple view controller ie. stage 1 (name/address) stage 2 (email, eye color) stage 3.. etc etc then on the last stage have it all persisted. Or should I be persisting on each step, like an iPhone? Thanks!

Comment: Re: syntax ... `label2.stringValue = @"String";` is newer vs. what you quoted in the question.  You can use dot-notation keypaths vs. square brackets in objective-C code now.  Re: Data colection over multiple views & VCs... that's an OSX MVC question, and the answer is often core data, or bindings, or both.